# How to map extra keys in linux?

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard, xmodmap

I'm running archlinux on my thinkpad x1 carbon 5th gen which has some extra keys. These keys currently do nothing and I'd like to remap them.

Firstly, I tried getting their keycodes via `xev` but they weren't being detected so I found out their keycodes via evtest.

Here are the results:

```
Event: time 1519668920.038747, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 45
Event: time 1519668920.038747, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 364 (KEY_FAVORITES), value 1
Event: time 1519668920.038747, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1519668920.038836, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 45
Event: time 1519668920.038836, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 364 (KEY_FAVORITES), value 0
Event: time 1519668920.038836, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1519668923.198764, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 49
Event: time 1519668923.198764, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 374 (KEY_KEYBOARD), value 1
Event: time 1519668923.198764, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1519668923.198883, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 49
Event: time 1519668923.198883, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 374 (KEY_KEYBOARD), value 0
Event: time 1519668923.198883, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

So tried mapping them to regular keys using xmodmap. For ex.

`keycode 374 = F13`
or

`keycode 374 = XF86LaunchB`

but was unsuccessful. How do I go about this? I have also tried to set the scan codes to keycodes via
`setkeycoder 45 255` but to no avail.

Comment: X11 protocol uses 1 byte so keycodes over 255 are invalid, and `xmodmap` and `setxkbmap` can't help you here.  maybe remap them with a udev `hwdb` override?  (`xkbcommon` under Wayland compositors won't have this issue, though any Xwayland clients probably still will.)

Comment: If it is not a usb keyboard you can use `setkeycodes` but you must renumber it to a value less than 255-8 i.e. 247 because 8 will get added to it for the X11 server.

Comment: @quixotic I'm using Xorg, can you advise me something to use with it?

Comment: @meuh yes it's not a USB keyboard, it's the inbuilt keyboard on my laptop. I tried setting the scancode to 247 using `setkeycodes 45 247` and then `xmodmap -e 'keycode 255 = XF86AudioMute'` to test but no success..

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that comes to mind is [Gianni Ceccarelli's patched `xf86-input-evdev`](https://www.thenautilus.net/SW/xf86-input-evdev/) which adds a new `xorg` configuration option called `event_key_remap` (details on his page).
I can't test it with an actual keyboard - my laptop keyboard doesn't produce keycodes above `255` - but I've successfully used it in the past to [remap buttons on remote controls for mythTV setups](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/remapping_remote_control_key_codes_greater_than_255).